# How to specify GCC Version in Azure Devops Linux Client

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

This feels like an obvious problem, but despite a lot of Googling I can't find an answer.

The available software list for the Azure Devops Linux client lists GCC 7.4.0 (https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/linux/Ubuntu1604-README.md)

However, the default GCC version in Ubuntu 16.04 is GCC 5.4.0. How do I make the client switch to 7.4.0? I can find example Tasks for changing Ruby or Python version, but not one for GCC.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

To use GCC 7, set the `CC` and `CXX` variables to `gcc-7` and `g++-7` respectively.
So your job configuration in `azure-pipelines.yml` should look like this:

```
jobs:
- job: Linux
  pool:
    vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
  variables:
    CC: gcc-7
    CXX: g++-7
```

Comment: This is correct. At the time I asked the question GCC 7 had not actually been rolled out to all build machines: [link](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/issues/724)